# Jena CLI tool to validate RDF?

Tags: rdf, jena

I have an RDF file and I want to validate that RDF file using Jena's command line tools.  Which of the `.bat` files distributed with Jena can be used to a validate a (hopefully legal) RDF file? How is the command invoked?

Answer (score 3):

It is `riot.bat`. The command is:

```
riot.bat --validate <location with name of the file>
```